# Emacs - automatically place cursor in buffer selection window

Tags: emacs

When I pull up the buffer selection window in emacs, **Ctrl-X Ctrl-B**, I then have to **Ctrl-X o**  to put the cursor in the new buffer.

Is there to make the cursor automatically active in the new buffer window after **Ctrl-X Ctrl-B**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to set `C-x C-b` to run `buffer-menu`, `buffer-menu-other-window` or `electric-buffer-menu` instead (put e.g. `(global-set-key "\C-x\C-b" 'electric-buffer-menu)` in your `.emacs`).

There are many alternative packages for buffer switching. As this is a rather personal choice, I'll just point you to the [wiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryBufferSwitching).

Comment: Very neat, thanks. I went with electric-buffer-list as it automatically expands the selection to the whole window.